# How to get checked value of checkbox if use array as a model in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wonder if I use array as model for multiple-checkbox list, how can I check which items is checked and which are unchecked efficiently rather than compare one by one with that array?

```
<ul>
<li v-for="task in tasks">
<input type="checkbox" :id="task.title" :value="task" v-model="selectedTasks" @change="handleTasks(task)">
<label :for="task.title">{{task.title}}</label>
</li>
</ul>


new Vue({
  data: {
      tasks: [
        { title: 'Go to the store' },
        { title: 'Clean the house' },
        { title: 'Learn Vue.js' }
      ],
      selectedTasks: []
  },
})
```

Comment: the selected task objects will be in the array. I am unsure exactly what you are really trying to ask or do.

Comment: @JacobGoh In my example, that selectedTasks can hold value that I checked, but I also want to know if one item is checked or unchecked when I click on it( that current design can not tell me that by giving me one variable )

Answer (score 4):

You could add a property to each `task` (e.g., `checked`) and bind that to each input's `v-model`, making it trivial in code to check whether a task is checked/selected:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [
        { title: 'Go to the store', checked: false },
        { title: 'Clean the house', checked: false },
        { title: 'Learn Vue.js', checked: false }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clearCheckedTasks() {
      this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(x => !x.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="task.title" v-model="task.checked">
      <label :for="task.title">{{task.title}}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <button @click="clearCheckedTasks">Clear checked tasks</button>
  
  <h3>tasks (live)</h3>
  <pre>{{tasks}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, in this way, how can I keep that model array "selectedTasks"? What I want is more like I want to keep that selectedTasks array to hold all selected items and when I click any item, I still able to get if it is checked or unchecked

Answer (score 4):

based on your comment that "I also want to know if one item is checked or unchecked when I click on it", I would use the DOM Event object to detect if it's checked.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/m480bupd/6/

add `@click="clickHandler"` to the input

```
<input type="checkbox" :id="task.title" :value="task" v-model="selectedTasks" @change="handleTasks(task)" @click="clickHandler">
```

use `e.target.checked` to get the `checked`

```
methods: {
    clickHandler(e) {
        console.log(e.target.checked);
    },
    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the loop index:

```
<li v-for="(task, index) in tasks">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="task.title" :value="task" v-model="selectedTasks[index]" @change="handleTasks(task)">
  <label :for="task.title">{{task.title}}</label>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, in this way, how can I keep all the value I selected and remove unselected?